# PostgreSQL seems to be using an old version after update

Tags: postgresql, version, postgresql-9.1, psql

I uninstalled my PostgreSQL because I'm trying to use version 9.1.9. I tried reinstalling it. It successfully installed from what I can see.

However, when typing in `psql --version` on the command line, I get that it is still using version 9.0.10

How can I make it use the new version?

Answer (score 1):

[`psql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/psql/info) is the command line interface and its version can be independent of the Postgres server.

To get the version of the server software run `SELECT version()` against the database you are connected to (from within psql). Though it is possible to interact with different versions, some obvious limitations apply. I suggest you uninstall the outdated `psql` as well and use the version matching the server.

Comment: Okay thanks, it looks like the server version is 9.1.9, but when I'm trying to get data from my postgresql database from heroku, i get that my pg_dump version is 9.0.10 - is there a way to update pg_dump and psql? How do i do this?

Comment: @user594623: That depends on a lot of details you did not supply. I suppose you start another question providing the relevant information if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: @user594623: OS and version, possibly packet format and source. What did you do to update? Any error messages or warnings. Make it a *new* question. But try to search for similar answers first. Here and on serverfault.com and Google. The answer is most probably already there. It's a standard problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this on a UNIX/Linux system the problem is likely to do with where psql is being called from. It doesn't sound like the old version got removed and you're still calling it when you run psql. Try running this:

> which psql

That will tell you the full path of what gets invoked when you run just psql. To see if there are other instances of psql installed on your system try running:

> sudo updatedb

(you'll need to put in your password here). And then:

> locate psql

Your system likely uses some kind of package manager, which controls which packages are installed. For example, Ubuntu/Debian use dpkg, Redhat uses yum, you may be using something like fink or macports if you are using OSX.